# How can I show thumbnails for pages of an uploaded document (.pdf, .rtf, .doc & .docx)?

Tags: php, css, google-docs, google-docs-api, google-document-viewer

Revisiting an old site I created a while ago, for a client, I used to use PHP code similar to:

`echo "<div style='display:inline;'><a href='". $uploadedFileURL ."' target='_blank'><img src='https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=". $uploadedFileURLEncoded ."&a=bi&pagenumber=". $docPageNumber ."&w=240' alt='Doc Preview - Page ".$docPageNumber."' title='Doc Preview - Page ".$docPageNumber." class='previewImage' style='width:240px;min-height:311px;display:inline;margin-right:25px; onerror='this.style.display=\"none\"' >...`

to display at least 6 pages of any given document the user uploaded.

I also had validation checks in place, to check for invalid document, or image types, such as ".exe". The PHP array for accepted file types included: `"gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png", "bmp", "tiff", "pdf", "rtf", "doc", "docx"`

I rendered the images by resizing only the width them to thumbnail size, with markup within the page, so they still work, thankfully!

However, I used Google Docs Viewer to handle the thumbnails of the document file types.

But now, Google Docs Viewer no longer supports thumbnail creation!

What are my options?

Thanks in Advance!

-James A.